# Can CodeFluent Generate a FileTable in SQLServer

Tags: codefluent

I am trying to use a FileTable for attachments in a CodeFluent application on SQLServer 2014, but can't seem to get CFE to generate the proper SQL (CREATE TABLE .... AS FileTable).

Does anyone know how this can be defined in the model?

Answer (score 1):

No, CodeFluent Entities doesn't generate FileTable. You can create it in a SQL script and add the script in your solution: [SQL Server Producer - Custom scripts](http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/StandardProducers_SQLServer_CustomScripts.html)

However you can use FileTable to store the blobs. There are 2 ways to use FileTables:

Using the file system API: The FileTable is accessible as a classic folder so you can use the filesystem binary service

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="Sample"type="CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentConfigurationSectionHandler, CodeFluent.Runtime" />
  </configSections>
  <Sample binaryServicesTypeName="filesystem" fileSystemBlobStorageRootPath="path to file table" />
</configuration>
```

Using T-SQL: this method is not supported out of the box by CodeFluent Entities. However you can support them by creating a class that inherits from `CodeFluent.Runtime.BinaryServices.BaseBinaryLargeObject` and override methods such as `ProtectedSave`, `PersistenceLoad`, `PersistenceDelete`, `GetOutputStream`, `GetInputStream`. Then you can declare you binary service in the configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Sample" type="CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentConfigurationSectionHandler, CodeFluent.Runtime" />
  </configSections>

  <Sample binaryServicesTypeName="Sample.FileTableBinaryServices, Sample" />
</configuration>
```